# mysql query join display 0 value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, left-join

I need to display sum from relation tables just like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x38K4.png)

this is my query:

```
select p.p_kode, p.name as p_name, sum(m.money) as jum
from person p
left join money as m on m.p_kode = p.`p_kode`
where m.date >= "2020-04-10" and m.date <= "2020-04-13"
group by p.p_kode
```

but still not like what I want. K003 still not display with `jum = 0` value.
please help. Thanks!

Comment: i think you need add  `p.name` into group by section

Comment: Move the condition `m.date >= "2020-04-10" and m.date <= "2020-04-13"` to the ON clause.

Comment: @MahdyAslamy still not work

Comment: @forpas how is that suppose to be like?

Comment: `on m.p_kode = p.p_kode and m.date >= "2020-04-10" and m.date <= "2020-04-13"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the condition from the `where` clause to the `on` part of the `left join` - otherwise, the condition becomes mandatory, and evicts rows from `person` for which the `left join` came back empty:

```
select p.p_kode, p.name as p_name, coalesce(sum(m.money), 0) as jum
from person p
left join money as m 
    on  m.p_kode = p.p_kode
    and m.date >= '2020-04-10' 
    and m.date <= '2020-04-13'
group by p.p_kode
```